# How to dynamically insert JSON data into a PHP array for foreach

Tags: php, json, database

I have the following PHP code, which gets executed when I hit the Submit button in a form:

```
// Save data
if(isset($_POST['save'])){

        $newDataArr = array();

        foreach ($data_array[0] as $k=>$v){

            $newDataArr[] = array($k => $_POST[$k]);

        }// ./ foreach

        echo json_encode($newDataArr);
}
```

The echo I get is the following:

```
[{"ID->id":"esKZSCDfIC"},{"DT->createdAt":"2020-01-26T13:02:42"},{"DT->updatedAt":"2020-01-26T13:02:42"},{"ST->aString":"hey1"},{"NU->number":123},{"GPS->coords":["2.2222","44.4444"]},{"BL->aBool":false},{"AR->theArray":["xx","ww"]},{"FL->theFile":"https:\/\/xscoder.com\/xserver\/uploads\/6dydDtoTt5JjZzFc5L5V_image.jpg"},{"PO->userPointer":"vbN3b0C7bC"}]
```

Then I'll have to add that array into my JSON file as it follows:

```
$data = json_encode(array_values($newDataArr), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
file_put_contents('Test.json', $data);
```

But of course the syntax of my `$newDataArr` is not the right one, each JSON object must not be inside the **{ }**, so this:

```
{"ID->id":"esKZSCDfIC"},
```

must become:

```
"ID->id":"esKZSCDfIC",
```

Is there a way to dynamically create a valid JSON array and push it to my Test.json file?

I've been through many posts on StackOverflow, but the result I get is always the same. I must use the PHP code above to get keys and values from my HTML inputs.

Comment: Read the json file, run `json_decode()` on it to make it a valid PHP data structure, add you new info to it, then convert it back to a jsonString `json_encode()` the new structure then write it to a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating and pushing a new array on each iteration, set the values this way:

`$newDataArr[$k] = $_POST[$k];`

Hope this helps.

Comment: How does that differ from what OP posted?

Comment: @Andreas The difference is described in the answer. Instead of pushing a new array for each property, you add that property as an index in the newDataArr array.